# How to include YouTube iframe API in Magento 2 layout template?

Tags: magento2, script, requirejs-config.js, external-script

I'm using Magento v2.4.1 and i want to show a youtube video on my storefront home page and control it using youtube iframe API in .phtml file, how can I correctly load this youtube iframe API in my .phtml file? because I need to include the script file from https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api instead of local dir

reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: You can directly call `phtml` on home page and add your code in phtml file

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `phtml` to Home page using:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="youtube" template="Magento_Theme::youtube.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/youtube.phtml

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: {
        'playsinline': 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```